# Chartjs 2 Line Graph Single Stroke Between Datasets

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to make a line graph with a single stroke between each datapoint on the graph. There should be a small space between each side of the datapoint.

[image]

I see that the docs say to use `borderDash` but the strokes will run through my datapoints instead of only between. I looked for a way to add padding/margin around each datapoint but I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `borderDash` limitation that you pointed out, I think the easiest way to get the desired effect is to use a combination of `pointRadius`, `backgroundColor`, `pointBorderColor`, and `pointBorderWidth`.

This works by creating a white border around each point that makes it looks like there's a gap.

For example:

```
backgroundColor: '#000',
pointRadius: 5,
pointBorderColor: '#fff',
pointBorderWidth: 3,
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Chart with borders around point]

And here's a runnable snippet:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: [{
      borderColor: '#000',
      backgroundColor: '#000',
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      lineTension: 0,
      data: [6.06, 82.2, -22.11, 21.53, -21.47, 73.61, -53.75, -60.32, -30, 20, 22, 25],
      label: 'Dataset',
      fill: false,
    }, ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```